# Rcpp function to construct a function

Tags: r, function, rcpp, return-type

In R the possibility exists to have a function that creates another function, e.g.

```
create_ax2 <-  function(a) {

  ax2 <- function(x) {
    y <- a * x^2
    return(y)
  }

  return(ax2)
}
```

The result of which is

```
> fun <- create_ax2(3)
> fun(1)
[1] 3
> fun(2)
[1] 12
> fun(2.5)
[1] 18.75
```

I have such a complicated create function in R which take a couple of arguments, sets some of the constants used in the returned function, does some intermediary computations etc... But the result is a function that is way too slow. Hence I tried to translate the code to C++ to use it with Rcpp. However, I can't figure out a way to construct a function inside a C++ function and return it to be used in R.

This is what I have so far:

```
Rcpp::Function createax2Rcpp(int a) {

  double ax2(double x) {
    return(a * pow(x, 2));
  };

  return (ax2);
}
```

This gives me the error 'function definition is not allowed here', I am stuck about how to create the function.

EDIT: The question [RcppArmadillo pass user-defined function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14428687/rcpparmadillo-pass-user-defined-function) comes close, but as far as I can tell, it only provides a way to pass a C++ function to R. It does not provide a way to initialise some values in the C++ function before it is passed to R.

Comment: This is not an Rcpp issue, C++ don't allow local function declarations. Thus, you need either to define this function outside local scope or wrap it in the class.

Comment: @m0nhawk of course it does

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux Of course I can use `std::function` and lambdas, but you can't define them like in the code above.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RcppArmadillo pass user-defined function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14428687/rcpparmadillo-pass-user-defined-function)

Comment: I edited with an explanation why it is different to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14428687/rcpparmadillo-pass-user-defined-function. Could you give an example of how to construct such a function using lambdas?

Comment: Okay, so you want an Rcpp function that creates another Rcpp function? Why? (And think carefully why that might be challenging if a compiled language is involved.)

Comment: @m0nhawk no, he wants to have a function with a closure

Comment: I cannot make any sense of this question.  R code is meant to be organised in package, and we support that mode pretty well.  What you suggest here is ... just a wee bit unusual. Maybe time for you to re-read some of our vignettes?

Comment: It was a question out of curiosity. I can easily circumvent the "problem" by defining a function `double ax2(double x, int a)`, but I was wondering if there was a way to fix `a` when creating the function. (My function has a lot more of those "constants" to be set).

Comment: If you had asked the function that way I could have pointed you to RcppDE where we used this idiom to pass an environment from R to C++.

Comment: I will have a look at it, thanks. My bad if the question was not clear, I'm not very familiar with Rcpp (yet).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, as far as I understand, you want a function returning function with a closure, a.k.a. " the function defined in the closure 'remembers' the environment in which it was created."

In C++11 and up it is quite possible to define such function, along the lines

```
std::function<double(double)> createax2Rcpp(int a) {
    auto ax2 = [a](double x) {  return(double(a) * pow(x, 2)); };
    return ax2;
}
```

What happens, the anonymous class and object with overloaded `operator()` will be created, it will capture the closure and moved out of the creator function. Return will be captured into instance of std::function with type erasure etc.

But! C/C++ function in **R** requires to be of a certain type, which is *narrower* (as an opposite to *wider*, you could capture *narrow* objects into *wide* one, but not vice versa).

Thus, I don't know how to make from std::function a proper **R** function, looks like it is impossible.

Perhaps, emulation of the closure like below might help

```
static int __a;

double ax2(double x) {
    return(__a * pow(x, 2));
}

Rcpp::Function createax2Rcpp(int a) {
    __a = a;

    return (ax2);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. The goal was indeed to create a function which 'remembers' the environment in which it was created such that I do not need pass the extra variables (in this case `a`) around. As this seems to be impossible, I'm marking this as accepted and will directly define the function as `double ax2(double x, int a)`.