# using `XPtr` to create pointer to a user defined function in Rcpp

Tags: r, rcpp, r-package

--------- **Adding a summary of the problem** ---------------------------------

I want to create a `externalpointer` for a user defined function which can be passed to the another function. The user will provide function name as a string, my question is how can I convert that into a function pointer, after checking that the user provided string (say `fstr`) matches with the name of the function that was created by the user, i.e.

```
if (fstr == "<USER_DEFINED_FUNCTION_NAME>")
  XPtr<funcPtr> fun(new funcPtr(&<USER_DEFINED_FUNCTION_NAME>), true);
else
  Rcpp::Rcout << "Supply the correct function name" << std::endl;
```

since, I don't know the name of the function created by the user, essentially the problem is - how can I get the string stored in the variable `fstr`?

The full problem is described below. Of course, I could be thinking of this problem in a totally wrong way and there may be a better way to create a function pointer to a user defined function.

Thanks

---

I am writing a package which provides a wrapper around the `cvode` solver for solving ODEs from the SUNDIALS ODE solving C library. The C function which describes the right hand side of the ODEs must be have the signature

```
int <FUNCTION_NAME> (realtype t, N_Vector y, N_Vector ydot, void *user_data)
```

where `realtype`, `N_Vector` are datatypes defined in the library and `t` is time, `y` is the vector of states (dependent variables) and `ydot` is the rate of change of those variables w.r.t. time.

I have written a package which provides a wrapper around the `cvode` function in this library to solve ODEs expressed as above. The package source code can be found [here](https://github.com/sn248/Rcppsbmod). The `cvode` function can be used to solve the example in SUNDIALS provided as follows:

I create a `test.cpp` (pasted below) which describes the RHS of ODEs, it also has the exported function to create `externalpointer` for the function which gets exported to R. Note that `NV_Ith_S` is also defined by the library. Also, a good example about function pointers in `Rcpp` can be found [here](http://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/passing-cpp-function-pointers/)

First I run `Rcpp::sourceCpp(test.cpp)`, then I run `my_fun <- putFunPtrInXPtr()` to create a external pointer `my_fun` to my `test` function in `test.cpp`. Finally, after loading the package, I run the command

```
time_t <- c(0.0, 0.4, seq(from = 10.4, len = 12, by = 10)) # time vector
cvode(time_t, c(1,0,0), my_fun, 1e-04, c(1e-08, 1e-08, 1e-08))
```

to get results on console successfully. Here the second argument is the initial conditions (IC), `my_fun` is the pointer to ODE function, third argument is relative tolerance and fourth argument is absolute tolerance. See details about `cvode` [here](https://github.com/sn248/Rcppsbmod/blob/master/src/cvode.cpp).

My question is this - I want to change the `cvode` in my package so that it can take function name as a string, i.e. `cvode(NumericVector time, NumericVector IC, std::string fstr, double reltol, NumericVector abstol)`, instead of `cvode(NumericVector, NumericVector, SEXP, double, NumericVector)` where the string `(fstr)` is the user given name which should be same as the same of the function defined in `.cpp` file (here `test` function in `test.cpp`).

I am thinking in my `cvode` function, I can write

```
if (fstr == "<USER_DEFINED_FUNCTION_NAME>")
  XPtr<funcPtr> fun(new funcPtr(&<USER_DEFINED_FUNCTION_NAME>), true);
else
  Rcpp::Rcout << "Supply the correct function name" << std::endl;
```

However, I cannot think of any way of getting information regarding the USER_DEFINED_FUNCTION_NAME. Essentially, I want `fun` to point to the USER_DEFINED_FUNCTION_NAME, but can't think of any way.

In the end, I actually want the RHS function defined in `.cpp` to have the signature `int <FUNCTION_NAME>(double t, NumericVector y, NumericVector ydot, void *user_data)`, from which I create a function with the correct signature to be fed to `cvode`, but not sure how this is possible also.

I would be very thankful for any guidance. Thanks!

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

#include <cvode/cvode.h>               /* prototypes for CVODE fcts., consts. */
#include <nvector/nvector_serial.h>    /* serial N_Vector types, fcts., macros */
#include <cvode/cvode_dense.h>         /* prototype for CVDense */
#include <sundials/sundials_dense.h>   /* definitions DlsMat DENSE_ELEM */
#include <sundials/sundials_types.h>   /* definition of type realtype */

int test (realtype t, N_Vector y, N_Vector ydot, void *user_data){

  // static keyword before int is not really required here

  NV_Ith_S(ydot,0) = -0.04 * NV_Ith_S(y,0) + 1e04 * NV_Ith_S(y,1) * NV_Ith_S(y,2);
  NV_Ith_S(ydot,2) = 3e07 * NV_Ith_S(y,1) * NV_Ith_S(y,1);
  NV_Ith_S(ydot,1) = -NV_Ith_S(ydot,0) - NV_Ith_S(ydot,2);

  return(0);

}

// declare funcPtr as a type for function pointer to a function with the
// signature same as function which describes the RHS for ODEs
// see reference here - http://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/passing-cpp-function-pointers/
typedef int (*funcPtr)(realtype t, N_Vector y, N_Vector ydot, void *user_data);

// [[Rcpp::export]]
XPtr<funcPtr> putFunPtrInXPtr() {

  // return(XPtr<funcPtr> (new funcPtr(&test)));
    XPtr<funcPtr> testptr(new funcPtr(&test), true);
    return testptr;

}
```

Comment: Could you provide a *minimal* example that reproduces your problem?

Comment: I  have added a summary. I don't have an example as I am stuck with not understanding a basic concept. Hope the summary helps, else I will try to cook up a contrived example.

Comment: To echo what Florian said, we don't have any of the specific headers you use, so it makes it difficult to help. One thing though is that you should definitely use `false` as the second argument of the `XPtr` constructor so that `delete` is not called. The construct `new funcPtr(&fun1_cpp)` in the article you mention feels wrong.

Comment: @RomainFrancois and Florian - Thanks for your comments, to me it seems this approach of trying to find function name might not be the right way. I am thinking of trying another approach in my package. Anyway, thanks for your comments.

Comment: Have you read the answer from [RcppArmadillo pass user-defined...](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14428758/4408538)? There is a link in the answer there to the Rcpp gallery ([Passing user-supplied C++ functions...](http://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/passing-cpp-function-pointers/)).