# An Rcpp function calling a single Rcpp function from a bunch of functions

Tags: r, rcpp

I am trying to write an Rcpp function `fun1` that can call another Rcpp function generically (let's say `fun2`). One possibility I could think about is to use an input argument that is a string containing the name of the function `fun2`.

```
 NumericVector fun1(NumericVector x, std::string name_of_fun2) { 
         
         NumericVector y = fun2(x);
         return(y);
}
```

I do not know how to fill in the missing code as I'm new to C++. One thing that I tried and that works is to use `switch` `case` statements, but the problem is that I need to define a big list of all possible functions `fun2` that could be called in advance.

Comment: There are several ways to attack this. Using a `switch` is one valid option, but it may be better to study `C++` a little more as there are ample standard `C++` approaches to this problem (e.g. virtual functions).

Comment: Functions could be passed as arguments using pointers or even using the standard library functional. Since your functions will be different each time, you must have a generic idea of what they are then create a template. I presume you are going down to the basics of R. I have never been in a position to do this

Comment: There is also this question https://stackoverflow.com/q/14428687/4408538 which was turned into an excellent `Rcpp` gallery post https://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/passing-cpp-function-pointers/.

Comment: @JosephWood Thanks for your helpful answer. The gallery post has also an if else statement (if (fstr == "fun1") ) similar to the switch case solution I mentioned. I was wondering if there is a way to access the function without such such a statement.